# To which directory should I install a program from a bash script?

Tags: bash, software-installation, scripts

I want to install Netbeans 7.0.1 with a bash script from the Netbeans website. The default directory chosen by the installer is `/home/geoffrey/netbeans-7.0.1`. But I do not think it belongs there.

Comment: Does the installer have an option '--help' or something similar, did you find/read any installation instructions?

Comment: It is easy to change the install directory. The problem was just which directory to choose.

Comment: Aha, well, maybe it's just me but I did not get that from your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it for all users, `/opt` is a great place.

`/opt` is for entire software packages (rather than those that are split up across the various directories). See the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/fhs/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES).

Google Chrome, for example, installs to `/opt`

Answer (score 2):

If you want it for a single user I would put it in ~/bin (or at least a link to the binary)

If you want it for all users, I would put it in /usr/local/bin (or at least a link to the binary).

Answer (score 2):

I've created an `~/apps` directory in which I store such external programs to avoid the home directory being cluttered.

I then create a symlink in `~/bin` to programs in `~/apps`. Storing everything in `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` is a bad idea since the folder contains other files (non-binaries) too.