# Where should I put programs that I download so they're available to all users?

Tags: binary, directory

Is there a convention that says where I should put programs I download if I want to make them available to all users? Blender, for example, appears to have a compiled executable, but also other directories and files that it (presumably) depends on.

The answer to [To which directory should I install a program from a bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94969/to-which-directory-should-i-install-a-program-from-a-bash-script) recommended /opt, but it isn't in my $PATH by default, and my /opt happens to be empty despite installing a lot of stuff from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When installing user applications, where do "best practices" suggest they be located?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148/when-installing-user-applications-where-do-best-practices-suggest-they-be-loc)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The preferred method for that is `/opt`, although some people are known to put them in `/usr/local/bin`

As for your other question related to the Ubuntu Software center, not all packages in the Ubuntu Software Center are set to install to `/opt` - in fact, most of them don't follow that "standard".

Comment: So why isn't /opt included in $PATH "out of the box"?

Comment: @Evan I'm not sure. I'll update my answer if I find anything though.

Answer (score 1):

You will get varied opinions on this, even in the documentation.

http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch12.en.html#_compile_and_install_a_program

http://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard

On the second link, scroll down to /opt and /usr

As pointed out, I personally tend to use /usr/local as it is on the $PATH